# Swift iOS Remove microphone key from keyboard in code

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I want to remove microphone key from keyboard.But in code.
Can you help me?

Comment: This URL can be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105058/disable-dictation-button-on-the-keyboard-of-iphone-4s-new-ipad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there seems to be no simple command to do so. Best way is to create custom keyboard and edit yourself.

Check this cocopod for your app

[Custom keyboard](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager)

According to your question. Here is the link
[UITextInputCurrentInputModeDidChangeNotification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinputcurrentinputmodedidchangenotification)

Comment: thanks . if I want to disable microphone key. can i do that?

Comment: yes, UITextInputCurrentInputModeDidChangeNotification this to check which mode is on and disable any action if user press this button

Comment: thanks a lot . can you give me a sample cod  to do that ?

Comment: I have a textfield that i want to disable microphone key . can i do that?

Comment: https://cocoacasts.com/what-is-notification-name-and-how-to-use-it/
Here is shows swift example of doing so. Check notification.name If it is dictionary for example... call method to do nothing.

Comment: Please select my answer and upvote if you are happy with my answers

Comment: I read content of this link . but i cant use if for my code.can you give me a code that i can disable microphone key from keyboard?

Comment: for exaple i have a password textfield that i want to disable microphone for it.

Comment: I am not sure, what more you want ?
In the link it have state clearly everything with example. Also it does not matter. Notification is set for keyboard not for textfield. As soon the keyboard pop on view you can check from that point onwards what really happening and choose to do nothing once it is microphone