# Override iOS Speech Input Behaviors

Tags: ios, swift, speech-recognition

I'm developing an iOS application in Swift with voice and speech input. Instead of relying on Apple's speech-to-text services, I am substituting another speech recognition service. I can already programmatically record audio and interact with this alternate speech service.

When interacting with a textbox, I'd like the keyboard to show up (it currently does) but I'd like the speech icon to either:

- be rewired to send audio information directly to my service
- be disabled (no ability to send audio information to Apple's service)

I can find lots of information about using Apple's speech service but can't find information relating to switching out the speech-service backend.

Answer (score 2):

You **cannot modify** the dictation function of the default keyboard. You have to either create a custom keyboard or put a button over the user's keyboard that starts the custom dictation process.

If you want to hide the dictation option on the keyboard, [check out this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11105058/3151675). **Keep in mind that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12079125/3151675) uses a private API, which may get your app rejected.**